# Query that looks up the latest N Number rows when given list of single columnID

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my table looks like.

```
UUID        Varchar     Unique id 
CREATED_ON  TIMESTAMP   Instant
Encounter   Varchar     encounter
```

I need a query that looks up the latest N Number of rows by each encounter. So if there are 3 encounters they each can have up to N Number rows.

I tried to use sub queries but they are not working. I was able to retrieve latest n number of rows if it is a single encounter. But retrieving for each encounter seems very difficult. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it Oracle or Mysql ? Tags are quite confusing.

Comment: Updated my tags. It is oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you what you want:

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
(
   SELECT UUID, CREATED_ON, Encounter, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Encounter ORDER BY CREATED_ON DESC) AS rn
   FROM table1
) a
WHERE a.rn <= :your_number
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if i want to pass a list of encounters ?. Like where encounter IN(1,2,3).

Comment: Just add `WHERE` to inline view - ` ... FROM table1 WHERE Encounter IN (1,2,3) )a .... `

Comment: Thank you A1ex07. With this query i will get "rn" as a cloumnID. I'm trying to convert returned rows into JPA entities. So i don't want that rn column. Is there a way to take off rn ?

Comment: Instead of `a.*` specify column list explicitly  - `SELECT a.UUID, a.CREATED_ON, a.Encounter ...`

Comment: It is going to create a table which is not my entity. I'm not sure if JPA handles inner queries and returns the matching entity.